# Filter a table result using JQuery event click after press Enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am not able to filter the data that is in the records table after typing the search value I want in any field and pressing enter.

I have two fields to enter the data, salesman and customer, and I would like to make the filter from these fields, if I insert a seller and hit the enter key, filter the table data from the seller typed in the text field to seller , if I enter a client name in the client name field and hit Enter, retrieve the client data through the filter.

Every help is welcome

I already tried to do it this way, but it did not work very well, it only filters an inserted field, and when I click the enter button it does not do any work.

below the code snippet I tried:

```
$("#GrupoEmpresaAutoComplete").on("keyup", function () {
        searchText = $(this).val();
        searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
        searchText = searchText.replace(/\s+/g, '');
        $('.CelebreTableRow > td').each(function () {
            var currentTdText = $(this).text(),
                showcurrentTd = ((currentTdText.toLowerCase()).replace(/\s+/g, '')).indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
            $(this).toggle(showcurrentTd);
        });
    });
```

Form:

```
<div id="Filtros" class="accordion-body collapse in">
  <div class="accordion-inner">
   <div class="well">
      <form action="@Url.Action("Filtros")" method="POST" id="formFiltros">
       <fieldset>
         <div class="row-fluid">
           <div class="span6">
              @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IdGrupoEmpresa, "Salesman")
                <div class="controls">
                @Html.TextBox("GrupoEmpresaAutoComplete", "", new { placeholder = "Digite um vendedor(cnpj ou nome)..." })
                 @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IdGrupoEmpresa)
             </div>
         </div>
          <div class="span6">
             @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IdCliente, "Customer")
        <div class="controls">
             @Html.TextBox("ClienteAutoComplete", "", new { placeholder = "Digite um adquirente..." })
             @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IdCliente)
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  }
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Detect key press by `event.which` or `event.keyCode` value which should be `13` for `Enter`

```
$("#search-bar").on("kepress", function(e) {
      var k = event.keyCode || e.which;
      if (k == 13) {
        // filter and show result
      }
    }
```